# Restoring files to their original location

Tags: bash, shell

I have a recycle bin function that I'm trying to extend to restore the files back to their original location. My initial thoughts were to use:

```
readlink -f $arg
```

as a variable and redirect the output to a config file. I can't seem to get that bit working though, any ideas?

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried 
    `variablename=$(readlink -f $arg)`
    `echo $variablename>>file.cfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little suggestion (not complete: no testing, no error handling, no handling of equal basenames, ...):

```
#!/bin/bash

TRASH=${HOME}/.trash/
TCFG=${HOME}/.trashconfig

function moveToTrash
{
    FPATH=$(readlink -f "$1")
    echo $(sha1sum "${FPATH}" | cut -d " " -f 1):${FPATH} >> "${TCFG}"
    mv "$1" "${TRASH}"
}

function restoreFromTrash
{
    SUM=$(sha1sum "$1" | cut -d " " -f 1);
    FPATH=$(grep ${SUM} "${TCFG}" | cut -d ":" -f 2);
    mv "$1" "${FPATH}"
}

if [ ! -d ${TRASH} ] ; then
    mkdir -p ${TRASH}
fi

if [ $1 == "remove" ] ; then
    moveToTrash "$2"
fi

if [ $1 == "restore" ] ; then
    restoreFromTrash "$2"
fi
```

Usage:

```
touch foo
trash.sh remove foo
trash.sh restore ${HOME}/.trash/foo
```

Comment: sha1sum: testfile: No such file or directory
is all i got when I tried running it, haven't used sha1sum before, it's just a checksum command right? It's only the restore that isnt working it would seem.